# Do not run time count simultaneously

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a button that allows me to start / stop the timing of a user.

At this time, it is possible to start several counts on several users simultaneously.

Is there a way to only start one at a time? If I already have a count started, when trying to start a different row count, I want the previous row to be paused and the new row to start (the time from zero).

How can I apply this?

**html**

```
<button id="button-basic" dropdownToggle aria-controls="dropdown-basic">
        <img *ngIf="taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.ID]?.currentState === 'pause' || taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.ID] == undefined" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQcW6cJlI-KlS721hkuHDTMydZ_snrkhL9sm9wYHWRhd3FlvF1b&s" width="50" height="50">
        <img *ngIf="taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.ID]?.currentState ==='start'"
        src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190516/original/pngtree-pause-vector-icon-png-image_3791321.jpg" width="50" height="50">
        <img *ngIf="!taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.ID]?.currentState ==='start'"
        src="https://png.pngtree.com/png-clipart/20190516/original/pngtree-pause-vector-icon-png-image_3791321.jpg" width="50" height="50">
      </button>
            <ul id="dropdown-basic" *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-basic">
                <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item"
                        *ngIf="!taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.ID] || taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.ID].currentState === 'pause'"
                        routerLinkActive="active" (click)="startTimer(data)">Start</a></li>
                <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item"
                        *ngIf="taskService.timerForUsers[data.key.ID]?.currentState === 'start'"
                        routerLinkActive="active" (click)="pauseTimer(data)">Stop</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: *on several users* ? So you want this across requests? Angular only runs in the client. You need a server technology to synchronise this. As far as angular is concerned, you are *only start one at a time* but that is in the context of the Js running on that users browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your start timer function as follows,

this will check before starting any timer if existing time is running, if so it will stop it and start the requested timer.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwpbdc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
 startTimer(data) {

    // get remaining ids
    const pauseIds = [];
    this.data.forEach(d => {
      if (d.ID !== data.key.ID
        && this.taskService.timerForUsers[d.ID] !== undefined
        && this.taskService.timerForUsers[d.ID].currentState === 'start')
          pauseIds.push(d.ID);
    });

    // pause other timers
    pauseIds.forEach(id => {
      this.taskService.pauseTimer(id);
    });

    this.taskService.startTimer(data.key.ID);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have one timer at a time for a specific user just do it like this :

```
  startTimer(data) {
    if(this.currentTimer){
      this.taskService.pauseTimer(this.currentTimer.key.ID);
    }
   this.currentTimer = data;
   this.taskService.startTimer(data.key.ID);
  }

  pauseTimer(data) {
    this.currentTimer = undefined;
    this.currentTimer = this.taskService.pauseTimer(data.key.ID);
  }
```

working sample : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sdlgqn

as Liam said in comment, if you want to have only ONE timer across request, you have to implement it on the server side

Comment: The OP is already doing this. See their [service code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vc5ndg?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftask.service.ts) (handily not included in the question)

Comment: no he isn't, you can start multiple timer in his stackblitz, not in mine

Comment: `startTimer....clearInterval(currentUserTimer.interval);..` I guess it depends what the OP means by start timer, but I'm pretty sure this is not what the OP wants anyway

Comment: well maybe it's like this inside his service, but try his stackblitz and you will see, you can have multiple timer running

Comment: @Alann Your code also worked correctly, thank you very much!

Comment: you're welcome ! Since you only showed us component code in the post I thought you wanted to solve it inside the component, I think the other answer is the best solution for your problem :)